# angularJS in webstorm, display binding wrong

Tags: angularjs, webstorm

I am newly picking up angularJS, cannot figure out my situation here:
Everything goes fine when I just open official phonecat tutorial file. 
However, if I create my own project, the binding never displays well, it also shows out "{{ }}".

[image: index.html file looks like this]

[image: that's the app.js file]

Pictures show all I got here. I believe nothing wrong with the script referencing, just cannot figure out after tried hundred times.

Comment: Have you tried playing around with the src path of the script tag? I use WebStorm and the solution for reference errors like this is usually to remove the slash at the beginning or prepend a dot to the slash. First thing I'd try is `src="lib/angular.min.js"`, if that doesn't work I'd try `src="./lib/angular.min.js"`.

Comment: Look for errors in the console for your browser?

Answer (score 0):

It seems script referencing is not correct. Make sure that your script reference is correct.

I run the following code and it gave me the expected result.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body data-ng-app>
  <p>{{1+2}}</p>
</body>
</html>
```

See [Demo](https://jsbin.com/covepohipe/edit?html,output)

In the browser check the source. Does angular exist in your browser.

Comment: what do you mean by `No need to create any controller`?

Comment: There was an answer where it was suggested to create a controller. Anyway I am editing my answer. That answer has been deleted I can see now @PankajParkar